Class, struct, or interface method must have a return type
public class Main{
    public Test(string a){
        return a;
    }
    Main test = new Main("Hello World!");
}

выдает ошибку Class, struct, or interface method must have a return type, добавил return но ошибка осталась

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ - рекомендую, мне помогло

И что значит код public Test(string a), который возвращает строку, в классе Main?  Это и не конструктор, и не метод.

@NowhereMan у него public void Test(...) должно быть, очевидно.

Ошибка возникает из-за синтаксических и семантических проблем в вашем коде.
Ошибка "Class, struct, or interface method must have a return type" означает, что метод Test в вашем классе Main должен указать тип возвращаемого значения. В C# каждый метод должен указывать тип возвращаемого значения (или использовать void, если метод ничего не возвращает).
В стандартном консольном приложении на C# точка входа представляется статическим методом Main, который выглядит так:
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Код вашего приложения здесь
    }
}

если вы используете имя Main для других нужд это может привести к различным ошибкам
можно изменить имя класса на что-то другое, что не конфликтует с именем метода
Main, или измените имя метода Main на что-то другое.
public class TestConsole
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    // Конструктор класса TestConsole, чтоб не создавать конфликт классов
    public TestConsole(string a)
    {
        Text = a;
    }

    // Точка входа в программу Main 
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestConsole test = new TestConsole("Hello World!");
        System.Console.WriteLine(test.Text);
    }
}

или так
using System;

public class Program
{
    // Метод Test теперь объявлен вне метода Main, но статический
    public static string Test(string a)
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Вызов метода Test
        string result = Test("Hello");
        Console.WriteLine(result); // Вывод: Hello World
    }
}

ну или вот так
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Локальная функция внутри Main
        string Test(string a)
        {
            return a;
        }

        // Вызов локальной функции Test и вывод результата
        Console.WriteLine(Test("Hello World!").ToString()); // Вывод: Hello World
    }
}


Спасибо большое, но в коде вы указали static перед методом Main, но для чего это?

Компилятор C# требует, чтобы метод Main был static, иначе он будет выдавать ошибку (Метод Main является точкой входа в программу. Он вызывается при запуске приложения и не требует создания экземпляра класса для его вызова.) он должен быть объявлен как static, чтобы его можно было вызвать напрямую с класса, а не через экземпляр объекта. полезно ===> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c/416585#416585

В C# это соглашение — Main должен быть объявлен как статический метод с определенной сигнатурой (void Main(string[] args) или int Main(string[] args)). Это помогает языку и среде выполнения однозначно определить точку входа в приложение.
